# Error While trying to Use provider.getAddress Module

Tags: javascript, error, truffle-deployment, address.transfer

When I try to run this module, it giveas an error "TypeError: provider.getAddress is not a function".

```
const fs = require('fs')
const Web3 = require('web3')


function loadAccount (privateKeyFileName) {
  const providerUrl = 'wss://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/<key>'
  const chainId = 5 // Goerli testnet chain ID
  const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(privateKeyFileName, 'utf-8')
  const provider = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(providerUrl)

  return {
    ownerAddress: provider.getAddress(),
    web3js: new Web3(provider),
    provider
  }
}

module.exports = {
  loadAccount,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to create a account using the private key first, then is possible to obtain the public address.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const Web3 = require('web3')


function loadAccount (privateKeyFileName) {
  const providerUrl = 'wss://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/<key>'
  const chainId = 5 // Goerli testnet chain ID
  const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(privateKeyFileName, 'utf-8')
  const provider = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(providerUrl)
  const web3js= new Web3(provider);

  return {
    ownerAddress: web3js.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey).address,
    web3js: web3js,
    provider
  }
}

module.exports = {
  loadAccount,
}
```